# random document aggregate by two or more fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have questions list and they have structure like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a077c418fdf294df73bf7ea"
    },
    "author": "PinkyaRabbit",
    "question": "Что здесь литерал: var x = {};",
    "category": "Javascript шаблоны",
    "answers": [
        "var x",
        "{}",
        "var x = {};",
        "Нету тут его"
    ],
    "real": "{}",
    "description": "Литерал, это нейкое чистое значение, которое встречается в коде. Цифра, слово, объект - что  угодно",
    "users": [
        {
            "status": "good",
            "wasToday": true,
            "user": 471317129
        }
    ],
    "blockedBy": [],
    "date": "2017-11-12T01:40:01+03:00"
}
```

I need to pick one random, question for user. Each user have personal categories list. `blockedBy` its an array if user dont want to take. I pick personal categories list like array `user.categories` and try to make aggregate request.

```
TGquestions.aggregate([
          { $match: {
              users:{
                "status": "clear",
                "wasToday": false,
                "user": chatid
              },
              category: { $in: user.categories },
              blockedBy: { $ne: chatid}
            }},
            { $sample: { size: 1 } }
          ], (err, qq) => {
```

The problem is that looks like my random not working atall. For example, first picked question from category with name "Javascript", next will be same from "Javascript", and white question not ends all next will be from this category. When question in this category ends, with next category same problem. The worst in this is that queue of categories each time same. So my random aggregate totaly failed. How to fix this?

---

upd. example
I have a user

```
{
"_id": {
"$oid": "5a15aa31457bca063c01248b"
},
"chatid": 213229659,
"username": "iamRB01",
"baned": false,
"name": "Rina",
"categories": ["Javascript", "Java"],
}
```

And some questions from some categories. I changed `_id`'s to make all more readable.

```
{
"_id": "1",
"author": "PinkyaRabbit",
"question": "Что здесь литерал: var x = {};",
"category": "Javascript",
"answers": [
"var x",
"{}",
"var x = {};",
"Нету тут его"
],
"real": "{}",
"description": "Литерал, это нейкое чистое значение, которое встречается в коде. Цифра, слово, объект - что  угодно",
"users": [
{
"status": "clear",
"wasToday": false,
"user": 213229659
}
],
"blockedBy": [],
"date": "2017-11-12T01:40:01+03:00"
},
{
"_id": "2",
"author": "PinkyaRabbit",
"question": "Первым признаком конструктора является?",
"category": "Javascript",
"answers": [
"слово new",
"метод construct",
"имя пишется с большой буквы",
"возможно обращение через this"
],
"real": "имя пишется с большой буквы",
"description": "Если имя чего-то пишется с большой буквы в Javascript, то это конструктор (если код писал не криворукий рак)",
"users": [
{
"status": "clear",
"wasToday": false,
"user": 213229659
}
],
"blockedBy": [],
"date": "2017-11-13T16:20:50+03:00"
},
{
"_id": "3",
"author": "Xiroho",
"question": "Для записи пятеричной системы счисления используются цифры -",
"category": "Java",
"answers": [
"01234",
"0123456789",
"01",
"10"
],
"real": "01234",
"description": "",
"users": [
{
"status": "clear",
"wasToday": false,
"user": 213229659
}
],
"date": "2017-11-20T23:31:03+03:00",
"blockedBy": []
},
{
"_id": "4",
"author": "PinkyaRabbit",
"question": "Как проверить, есть ли элемент в массиве",
"category": "Javascript",
"answers": [
"сделать цикл с проверкой if(haystack[i]===needle){return true;}",
"использовать проверку через filter",
"использовать функцию indexOf",
"использовать функцию includes"
],
"real": "использовать функцию includes",
"users": [
{
"status": "clear",
"wasToday": false,
"user": 213229659
}
],
"description": "Хотя indexOf работает верно\nif(array.indexOf(\"test\") > -1){ result++; }\nона проигрывает includes по быстродействию\narray.includes(\"test\")\nпоэтому стоит использовать includes. Тем не менее, не все браузеры поддерживают includes, которая появилась только в 2016 году, поэтому indexOf знать тоже надо",
"blockedBy": [213229659],
"date": "2017-12-01T01:21:09+03:00"
}
```

I want to pick one random question of this collection. For example first id=2, next with id 3, next with id 1 but not with id 4 cuz user turned off this question. But in my script looks like `aggregate` random not working... =(

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirement. Could you please provide a small sample data set and describe the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that in nested arrays for picking real results needed to use `$elemMatch`.

```
  TGquestions.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        category: { $in: user.categories },
        users: {
          $elemMatch: {
            "status": "clear",
            "wasToday": false,
            "user": chatid
          }},
        blockedBy: { $ne: chatid}
      }},
      { $sample: { size: 1 } }
    ], (err, qq) => {
```